# Google Maps V3 - mouse position wrong

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented Google Maps API V3 on a page and for some reason the position of the mouse is off.

In the [image](http://tinypic.com/r/15evgoz/8), my mouse is in the red circle but the map thinks it's where the blue circle is.

This issue also affects the dragable points when using the directions service.

I build the map using the following:

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.42263, -7.9541);
var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds( );

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 53.42263, -7.9541 ),
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var clusters = [];
var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var spiderIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage (
    'http://www.irishcottageholidays.com/images/cottage1.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32,32),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(16,20)
)

oms.addListener('click', function(marker, event) {
    load_content(map, marker, iw, marker.id)
});

oms.addListener('spiderfy', function(markers) {
    for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i ++) {
      markers[i].setIcon(spiderIcon);
    }
    iw.close();
});

for (var i = 0; i < data.locations.length; i++) {

    var dataPhoto = data.locations[i];

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataPhoto.latitude,dataPhoto.longitude);

    latlngbounds.extend( latLng );

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        icon: 'http://www.irishcottageholidays.com/images/cottage1.png',
        map: map,
        id: dataPhoto.mID,
        title: dataPhoto.name
    }); 

    clusters.push(marker);
    oms.addMarker(marker);
}

var mcStyles = [
    {
        textColor: 'deeppink',
        textSize: 18,
        anchor: [17,0],
        url: '/assets/cms/images/cottage_cluster.png',
        height: 50,
        width: 50
    }
]

var mcOptions = {
    styles: mcStyles,
    gridSize: 5,
    maxZoom: 15
}

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, clusters, mcOptions);

map.fitBounds( latlngbounds );
```

Comment: Is this only in v=3.exp with Firefox 39.0?

Comment: Now you mention it yes - it works fine in Chrome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with Firefox 39.0 and v=3.exp.

- [issue 8278](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8278) in the issue tracker

Comment: Thanks - following the advice on the tracker I'm now using v=3 instead and all appears to be working correctly